# How can I set up JavaScript interpreter in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've been using WebStorm and I tried to configure a JavaScript interpreter but I couldn't.

The only thing that worked is Node.js interpreter, but it doesn't support DOCUMENT (e.g. `document.write()`) so I just need to make a configuration to run JS.

I'm beginner at JavaScript programming.

[image: WEBSTORM CONFIGURATIONS]

Answer (score 1):

`document` is only defined in browser, so you need to link your `.js` file to HTML page (`index.html`) via `<script src="main.js"></script>` and then use either **Run** or **Debug** action in HTML file right-click menu to execute your code